# Numerically robust $2\times2$ determinant?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

How can the determinant of a $2\times2$ matrix
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{vmatrix}
=
a d - b c
$$
be computed in floating point without suffering unnecessary catastrophic cancellation?

For a challenging case, consider the determinant:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
  10^9 & 10^9-1 \\
  10^9-1 & 10^9-2
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
  1\ 000\ 000\ 000 & 999\ 999\ 999 \\
  999\ 999\ 999 & 999\ 999\ 998
\end{vmatrix}
= -1.
$$

All of the numbers above are exactly representable in IEEE double precision arithmetic, including the determinant which is exactly $-1$.

But naively computing the determinant as $a b - c d$ in double precision produces $0$:
\begin{align}
   a b - c d &= 10^9 (10^9-2) - (10^9-1)^2 \\
             &= (10^{18} - 2\times10^9) - (10^{18} - 2\times10^9 + 1) \\
             &= (10^{18} - 2\times10^9) - (10^{18} - 2\times10^9) \quad \text{(the 1 is lost in rounding)} \\
             &= 0.
\end{align}

A seemingly reasonable alternative approach might be to reduce the matrix to triangular form using determinant-preserving row operations; that is, gaussian elimination (possibly with some form of row and/or column pivoting), and then take the product of the diagonal entries in the reduced triangular matrix.

Trying that on the above example, we see that the upper-left entry $a$, being the entry with maximum magnitude, is already the optimal pivot, so no row or column permutation is done initially. So gaussian elimination proceeds to zero out the lower-left entry by subtracting $c/a=(10^9-1)/10^9$ times the first row from the second row, yielding:
\begin{align}
& 
\begin{vmatrix}
  10^9 & 10^9-1 \\
  0 & (10^9-2) - (10^9-1)\times(10^9-1)/10^9
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
  10^9 & 10^9-1 \\
  0    & (10^9-2) - (10^9 - 2 + 10^{-9})
\end{vmatrix} \\
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
  10^9 & 10^9-1  \\
  0    & (10^9-2) - (10^9-2)
\end{vmatrix} \quad
\text{(the $10^{-9}$ is lost in rounding)} \\
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
  10^9 & 10^9-1  \\
  0    & 0
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= 0.
\end{align}

So gaussian elimination, too, has failed on this example.

This example *can* be solved in double precision, via the following ad-hoc sequence of determinant-preserving row and column operations. Start with the original matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  10^9   & 10^9-1 \\
  10^9-1 & 10^9-2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Subtract the first row from the second:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  10^9 &  10^9-1 \\
  -1   & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Subtract the second column from the first:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1  & 10^9-1 \\
  0  & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then the determinant can be read off as $(1\times-1) - (10^9-1)\times0 = -1$, which is the correct answer.

Is there a general robust method?

Comment: You can use double-double arithmetic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-double_%28arithmetic%29#Double-double_arithmetic) or look for error-free transformations (for determinants). See also https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266013410_Further_analysis_of_Kahan's_algorithm_for_the_accurate_computation_of_2_x_2_determinants

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stable resolution of a $2\times2$ linear system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848574/stable-resolution-of-a-2-times2-linear-system)

Comment: Private companies tend to mention the applicability of their products. In your case you might state that, in order for your firm to correctly calculate such determinants, the elements of the matrices should not exceed $\sqrt[^n]{\text{MAX}_{\text{TYPE}}}$ where $\text{MAX}_{\text{TYPE}}$ is the maximal value for that particular type and $n$ is the dimension of your square matrix.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the problem you’re dealing with, it might be useful to notice that $ad - bc = (a-b)d-b(c-d)$. For the example you provide, it pretty much solves the issue. Just note that it will only make things better if you can expect $|(a-b)d|$ and $|b(c-d)|$ to be much smaller than $|ad|$ and $|bc|$.

Got the idea from here:

https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/09/26/polygon-area/